# django 1.2.x admin inline with custom relationship

Tags: django, admin, inline, relationship

I have 2 models:

models.py:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Record(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

and admin.py

```
class RecordInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Record

class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RecordInline]
```

Basically what I want to do is to display records where users are same (teacher.user == record.user) inline in Teacher's detail in admin. The problem is that Teacher and Record do not have direct relationship, so I'm looking for a way to define this relationship.
How can I achieve this? I amd using Django 1.2.5 in my project

Answer (score 0):

You could override one of the ModelAdmin's methods, eg get_inline_instances

```
class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RecordInline]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request):
        # ...
```

Comment: sorry I forget to mention that I'm using Django 1.2.5, get_inline_instances was added in Django 1.4 so I can't use it in my project.